# Get the needed height to display all content within a View

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom view that gets loaded from nib that has a number of subviews. Some of these subviews contain labels which can be a dynamic height. This view ends up being added as a subview to a view that is in a scroll view.

Think `ScrollView > View > SubView > Dynamic Labels`

I am using auto layout constraints and therefore need to set the height of `SubView` that is required to display all the content in itself, so that the ScrollView will scroll the length necessary to display everything in the SubView.

I know with a UILabel, you can do something like `val neededLabelHeight = label.sizeThatFits(CGFloat(width: label.frame.height, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))` to get the needed height to display on a single label, but when I attempt to do this on a whole custom view loaded from nib, it just has the height of the view I have in my nib file.

Is there something similar for doing it on a view with more subviews, other than calculating the needed hight of the view by summing all the needed heights of its subviews and vertical constraints?

Comment: If you use the proper constraints, you won't need to do any calculations on heights - it's all handled for you by auto layout. Note that if you load the "root view" from a xib, auto layout sets `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true` for that view, so you need to set that to false (in code) to have it auto-size based on its content.

Comment: No, not in scrollview. In order for the `scrollview` to scroll the correct amount, the `View` needs to have a defined height. If you don't set a height constraint for a UILabel in `View`, it will grow and shrink as needed, and update the `View's` defined height. But if you use a `UIView` as a subview inside of `View`, you have to set a height constraint on that view because a UIView doesn't dynamically grow and shrink like a UILabel.

Comment: Nope... If you set the constraints correctly, the content of a view (its subviews) will "push out" the frame of the view. You do *not* need to explicitly set a height value.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong. Go build a ScrollView and stack some UIViews in there with no height constraints. It won't work and you will be thrown `Missing Constraint` errors

Comment: The missing constraint is the height constraint on the view inside of the scrollview

Comment: I've added an answer with a link to a sample project showing one approach. All done with constraints - no need for height calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example...

The XIB file looks like this:

[image]

Note: the Bottom Label has a constraint of `>= 8` to the bottom of the view. That way you don't have to worry about IB showing an error during design. Any extra space at the bottom will automatically "disappear" at run-time.

The Storyboard looks like this:

[image]

The scroll view has a red background (to make it easy to see). The labels and views containing buttons are laid-out and constraints are set as we normally set them.

The "Blue" view - `TheXIB Container View` - has a Height constraint of `120`, but is set as a Placeholder that will be removed at run-time, allowing the view loaded from the XIB to control its height. This will be the view to which we add our `Labels Holder View` from the XIB.

Here's how it looks with a small amount of text:

[image]

It's not scrollable, because there isn't enough content.

After tapping the "Add" buttons a few times, it looks like this:

[image]

and it ***is*** scrollable (we can see it's scrolled down in this image).

For folks who prefer using a "content view" as the "root" view of a scroll view, it works the same (orange view is the content view, inset by 8-pts on each side):

[image]

Here is a link to this example project: https://github.com/DonMag/LoadXIBIntoScroll

And here's a gif animation of it in action:

[image]

Comment: tried it, but it's not working. The scrollview scroll length doesn't change as I expand and collapse the subviews

Comment: I have my constraints set up properly like you have, but your project doesn't exactly simulate what I have. I was able to get it to work by just doing some calculations though

Comment: Well, I obviously can't say why your project isn't working... If you have the constraints set correctly - as I demonstrated - auto-layout should handle everything for you.